# Is it possible to write continuous nested functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, closures, anonymous-function, nested-function

I know this is the realm of closures and what not. But is it possible to continuously call nested anonymouse funtions?

Say I have this:

```js
function testing(input) {

  var testing = 0;
  (function() {
    testing = testing + 1;
  })()

  return "testing";
}
```

Can we have something like this `testing()()()()()()()` ?

Comment: `var testing = function() { return testing; };`

Comment: It's quite possible but not recommended

Comment: ^^ in this case a named function works better, because it keeps the refernec even if the assingment is to another name as in the function.

Comment: what is the wanted result of all? `'testing'` or a count?

Comment: @NinaScholz It should be a string. But the calls to testing can be arbitrary. Which is why its so confusing to understand. So for each call, we append a sting to something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an inner function which makes the update and has a `toString` method to get a primitive value.

```js
function testing() {
    function fn() {
        string += ++counter;
        return fn;
    }

    var counter = 0, 
        string = 'foo';

    fn.toString = _ => string;
    return fn();
}

console.log(testing());
console.log(testing()());
console.log(testing()()());
```

Comment: Amazing Job Nina, That's exactly what I was looking for. I can't believe we can have something like this in js.